# How do you convert a javascript array into an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

What's the best way to convert

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

into:

```
{
  "a": "b", 
  "c": "d",
  "e": "f"
}
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt or have some code you can show us?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```js
 Array.prototype.toObject  = function(){
   // var length = this.length - 1;
   return this.reduce(function(obj, val, index, array) {
      if(index %2 != 0) return obj;
      // if(index == length) return obj; // leave the 'e' property
      obj[val] = array[index+1];
      return obj;
   }, {})
 }
 
 
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c','d', 'e', 'f'];
console.log(a.toObject());
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using old good `for` loop and skipping every second iteration?

```js
 Array.prototype.toObject  = function(){
 // var len = this.length -1; // omit 'e' property
  var len = this.length; // leave 'e' property
 
  var obj = {};
  
  for (var i = 0; i< len; i=i+2){
    obj[this[i]] = this[i+1];
  }
  
  return obj;
}

var arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

console.log(arr1.toObject())
```

Comment: This is a much better answer as it's a lot clearer and not ES6 specific, so will work in all browsers.